# How to remove wup.exe from windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, malware, malware-removal

Wup.exe is consuming a lot of CPU power.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgDXB.png)
I have tried the following things:

1. To end task but it's useless, it starts again
2. To delete from registry, it also didn't work
3. Uninstalled all useless softwares
4. Reinstalled Chrome

Now, I am fed up, so somebody has any idea, how to remove it completely, I don't want to reinstall Windows please.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of Google searches for WUP.exe indicate it is a Virus  (Trojan Coin Miner). There is no wup.exe on my machines here.

Run a complete full scan with Windows Defender and see if Defender eliminates it.

You may have your own third party AV and so also use that.

If virus scanners are not able to clean it (that is not unknown), the complete elimination means backing up your machine and reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Yes I know , It's a trojan, windows defender is unable to stop it

Comment: You likely at this point must reinstall Windows to truly eliminate viruses.    I augmented my response.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try running Malwarebytes Free version before backup and reinstalling Windows? Generally it can find and remove things that Windows Defenders cannot. It could end up saving you more time and trouble if it does remove it. If that doesn't work, then I agree with John. Reinstall Windows.